# I want to redirect 15000 pages of my website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, search-engine-bots

I have a social networking website, and I want to redirect about 15000 previous web pages. I have been suggested by other experts to use 301 redirect.

All I want to know is that how redirection will not effect search engine ranking, is there any better way to move all the pages without any harm?

Answer (score 0):

301 redirects is the recommended method https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633